# Selecting/Joining tables from contacts table but get no ouput - Android

Tags: android, sqlite, contactscontract

I'm trying to go over all contacts using the `contacts`, `raw_contacts` and `data` tables.

From reading online I believe that `Contacts._id` is connected with `RawContacts.contact_id` and `Data.raw_contact_id` is connected with `RowContacts._id`. Am I right?

Believing in this I built this method:

```
public void testingContactsDatabase(String contactId)
    {
        final String[] projection = new String[] {
                Contacts._ID,
                Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
                Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID,
                Data.MIMETYPE,
                StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME, 
                StructuredName.FAMILY_NAME,
                StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME, 
                StructuredName.MIDDLE_NAME,
                StructuredName.PREFIX, // Common prefixes in English names are "Mr", "Ms", "Dr" etc.
                StructuredName.SUFFIX // Common suffixes in English names are "Sr", "Jr", "III" etc.
                };

        final String selection = Contacts._ID + " = " + contactId + " AND " 
                    + Contacts._ID + " = " + RawContacts.CONTACT_ID + " AND "
                    + Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID + " = " + RawContacts._ID;

        final Cursor curStructuredName = context.getContentResolver().query(
                ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, 
                projection, 
                selection, null,
                //new String[] {contactId, ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTACT_ID, RawContacts._ID},
                null
                );

        if(curStructuredName.moveToFirst())
        {
            Log.d("XYZ", "Found something");
        }
    }
```

But it never finds anything. I'm not sure if I'm using the correct `URI`, I've tried with different `URIs` and either got exceptions or same ouput.

Can someone point me out where I'm doing something wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved my problem. Here is my code working now:

```
// Get the structured name fields
    public ArrayList<String> getStructuredName(String contactId)
    {
        ArrayList<String> structuredList = new ArrayList<String>();

        final String[] projection = new String[] {
                StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME, 
                StructuredName.FAMILY_NAME,
                StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME, 
                StructuredName.MIDDLE_NAME,
                StructuredName.PREFIX, // Common prefixes in English names are "Mr", "Ms", "Dr" etc.
                StructuredName.SUFFIX // Common suffixes in English names are "Sr", "Jr", "III" etc.
        };

        final String filter = ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = ? AND " + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTACT_ID + " = ?"; 
        final String parameters[] = {StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE, contactId};

        Cursor cursor =  context.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, 
                projection, filter, parameters, null);

        if(cursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            for(cursor.moveToFirst(); !cursor.isAfterLast(); cursor.moveToNext())
            {
                final String displayName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME));
                final String familyName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(StructuredName.FAMILY_NAME));
                final String givenName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME));
                final String middleName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(StructuredName.MIDDLE_NAME));
                final String prefix = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(StructuredName.PREFIX));
                final String suffix = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(StructuredName.SUFFIX));

                structuredList.add(displayName);
                structuredList.add(familyName);
                structuredList.add(givenName);
                structuredList.add(middleName);
                structuredList.add(prefix);
                structuredList.add(suffix);

                Log.d(tag, "/////////////////////////////////////////////////////");
                Log.d(tag, "displayName: " + displayName );
                Log.d(tag, "familyName: " + familyName );
                Log.d(tag, "givenName: " + givenName );
                Log.d(tag, "middleName: " + middleName );
                Log.d(tag, "prefix: " + prefix );
                Log.d(tag, "suffix: " + suffix );
                Log.d(tag, "/////////////////////////////////////////////////////");

            }
        }

        cursor.close();
        return structuredList;

    }
```